# jqplot_how can I display the value at highlither in dateaxisrenderer?

Tags: jqplot, jqplot-highlighter

I wanted to draw two line series on the time axis, like this:

```
line 1 = [2011-01-01, 1], [2011-01-02, 2], [2011-01-03, 3],,,2011..
line 2 = [2012-01-01, 4], [2012-01-02, 5], [2012-01-03, 6],,,2012..
```

but I knew that dateaxisrenderer needed the same date between line1 and line2,
so I changed it to use the same dates, like this:

```
line 1 = [2012-01-01, 1], [2012-01-02, 2], [2012-01-03, 3],,,2012..
line 2 = [2012-01-01, 4], [2012-01-02, 5], [2012-01-03, 6],,,2012..
```

This solved that problem, but now I have a new problem.

The problem is that the line1's highlighter value is "2012-01-01, 1".
Its original value is "2011-01-01, 1".
I want to display the original value ("2011-01-01, 1") at the highlighter.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not need to change the line1 series values from 11 to 12 because the date axis render will handle the data it self defining the maximum and the minimum of the data set. Also after you give the data to the jqplot function you cannot expect to change the point highlight value unless you change the data again.